# Analytical solution to linear-regression coefficient estimates

Tags: regression

I'm trying to understand matrix notation, and working with vectors and matrices.

**Right now I'd like to understand how the vector of coefficient estimates $\hat{\beta}$ in multiple regression is computed.**

The basic equation seems to be

$$
\frac{d}{d\boldsymbol{\beta}} (\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X\beta})'(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X\beta}) = 0 \>.
$$

Now how would I solve for a vector $\beta$ here?

**Edit**: Wait, I'm stuck. I'm here now and don't know how to continue:

$    \frac{d}{d{\beta}} 
\left( 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 y_1 \\
 y_2 \\
 \vdots \\
 y_n
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
-
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1p} \\
 1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & \dots & x_{2p} \\
 \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
 1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \dots & x_{np} \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 \beta_0 \\
 \beta_1 \\
 \vdots \\
 \beta_p
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\right) '
\left( 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 y_1 \\
 y_2 \\
 \vdots \\
 y_n
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
-
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1p} \\
 1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & \dots & x_{2p} \\
 \vdots &  & & & \vdots \\
 1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \dots & x_{np} \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 \beta_0 \\
 \beta_1 \\
 \vdots \\
 \beta_p
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\right)
$

$
\frac{d}{d{\beta}} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \dots & x_{ip} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \beta_0 \\
 \beta_1 \\
 \vdots \\
 \beta_p
\end{pmatrix} \right)^2$

With $x_{i0} = 1$ for all $i$ being the intercept:

$
\frac{d}{d{\beta}} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - 
\sum_{k=0}^p x_{ik} \beta_k
 \right)^2
$

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @GaBorgulya, thanks for the edit, did not know about `smallmatrix`, so did not try to edit, since usual solution of breaking the formula in several lines would not have worked here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have

$\frac{d}{d\beta} (y - X \beta)' (y - X\beta) = -2 X' (y - X \beta)$.

It can be shown by writing the equation explicitly with components. For example, write $(\beta_{1}, \ldots, \beta_{p})'$ instead of $\beta$. Then take derivatives with respect to $\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{2}$, ..., $\beta_{p}$ and stack everything to get the answer. For a quick and easy illustration, you can start with $p = 2$.

With experience one develops general rules, some of which are given, e.g., in [that document](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/cas/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppD.d/IFEM.AppD.pdf).

**Edit to guide for the added part of the question**

With $p = 2$, we have

$(y - X \beta)'(y - X \beta) = (y_1 - x_{11} \beta_1 - x_{12} \beta_2)^2 + 
(y_2 - x_{21}\beta_1 - x_{22} \beta_2)^2$

The derivative with respect to $\beta_1$ is

$-2x_{11}(y_1 - x_{11} \beta_1 - x_{12} \beta_2)-2x_{21}(y_2 - x_{21}\beta_1 - x_{22} \beta_2)$

Similarly, the derivative with respect to $\beta_2$ is

$-2x_{12}(y_1 - x_{11} \beta_1 - x_{12} \beta_2)-2x_{22}(y_2 - x_{21}\beta_1 - x_{22} \beta_2)$

Hence, the derivative with respect to $\beta = (\beta_1, \beta_2)'$ is

$
\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
-2x_{11}(y_1 - x_{11} \beta_1 - x_{12} \beta_2)-2x_{21}(y_2 - x_{21}\beta_1 - x_{22} \beta_2) \\
-2x_{12}(y_1 - x_{11} \beta_1 - x_{12} \beta_2)-2x_{22}(y_2 - x_{21}\beta_1 - x_{22} \beta_2)
\end{array}
\right)
$

Now, observe you can rewrite the last expression as

$-2\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{11} & x_{21} \\
x_{12} & x_{22}
\end{array}
\right)\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1} - x_{11}\beta_{1} - x_{12}\beta_2 \\
y_{2} - x_{21}\beta_{1} - x_{22}\beta_2
\end{array}
\right) = -2 X' (y - X \beta)$

Of course, everything is done in the same way for a larger $p$.

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for exactly that type of pdf. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh, I thought I could do it myself now, but I can't. Can you tell me if my steps are right or if I should take "another way" to solve this?

Comment: @Alexx Hardt: My first equation in the edit is the same as your very last equation in the particular case where p = 2. So, you can mimic my calculations for components 3, 4, ..., p.

Comment: Thanks again :) I think I'll actually use all three suggestions. I'm building a .pdf which explains and sums up basic stats matrix algebra, because I somehow never wanted to learn it when I learned it in my classes. To solve it with three different ways will help me understand it better, I hope.

Comment: Oh, but this is for p=2 and n=2, right? I'll write it down with n=3 I think.

Comment: @Alexx Hardt: Yes, n=2 as well in my answer. You can also have a look at http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Algebra-Useful-Statistics-Probability/dp/0471866814. This book is a standard in statistics I think.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use formulas from [Matrix cookbook](http://web.archive.org/web/20110430075537/http://matrixcookbook.com/). We have

$$(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)=y'y-\beta'X'y-y'X\beta+\beta'X'X\beta$$

Now take derivatives of each term. You might want to notice that $\beta'X'y=y'X\beta$. The derivative of term $y'y$ with respect to $\beta$ is zero. The remaining term

$$\beta'X'X\beta-2y'X\beta$$

is of form of function

$$f(x)=x'Ax+b'x,$$

in formula (88) in the book in page 11,  with $x=\beta$, $A=X'X$ and $b=-2X'y$. The derivative is given in the formula (89):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=(A+A')x+b$$

so

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)=(X'X+(X'X)')\beta-2X'y$$

Now since $(X'X)'=X'X$ we get the desired solution:

$$X'X\beta=X'y$$

Comment: +1 mpiktas: Your solution is more ingenious than mine and I think it should be used in more complex practical situations.

Comment: @ocram, thanks. I would not call it ingenious, it is a standard application of existing formulas. You just need to know the formulas :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a technique for minimizing the sum of squares in regression that actually has applications to more general settings and which I find useful.

**Let's try to avoid vector-matrix calculus altogether.**

Suppose we are interested in minimizing 
$$
\newcommand{\err}{\mathcal{E}}\newcommand{\my}{\mathbf{y}}\newcommand{\mX}{\mathbf{X}}\newcommand{\bhat}{\hat{\beta}}\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\err = (\my - \mX \beta)^T (\my - \mX \beta) = \|\my - \mX \beta\|_2^2 \> ,
$$
where $\my \in \reals^n$, $\mX \in \reals^{n\times p}$ and $\beta \in \reals^p$. We assume for simplicity that $p \leq n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(\mX) = p$.

For any $\bhat \in \reals^p$, we get
$$
\err = \|\my - \mX \bhat + \mX \bhat - \mX \beta\|_2^2 = \|\my - \mX \bhat\|_2^2 + \|\mX(\beta-\bhat)\|_2^2 - 2(\beta - \bhat)^T \mX^T (\my - \mX \bhat) \>.
$$

If we can **choose** (find!) a vector $\bhat$ such that the last term on the right-hand side is zero for *every* $\beta$, then we would be done, since that would imply that $\min_\beta \err \geq \|\my - \mX \bhat\|_2^2$.

But, $(\beta - \bhat)^T \mX^T (\my - \mX \bhat) = 0$ for all $\beta$ if and only if $\mX^T (\my - \mX \bhat) = 0$ and this last equation is true if and only if $\mX^T \mX \bhat = \mX^T \my$. So $\err$ is minimized by taking $\bhat = (\mX^T \mX)^{-1} \mX^T \my$.

---

While this may seem like a "trick" to avoid calculus, it actually has wider application and there is some interesting geometry at play.

One example where this technique makes a derivation *much* simpler than any matrix-vector calculus approach is when we generalize to the matrix case. Let $\newcommand{\mY}{\mathbf{Y}}\newcommand{\mB}{\mathbf{B}}\mY \in \reals^{n \times p}$, $\mX \in \reals^{n \times q}$ and $\mB \in \reals^{q \times p}$. Suppose we wish to minimize
$$
\err = \mathrm{tr}( (\mY - \mX \mB) \Sigma^{-1} (\mY - \mX \mB)^T )
$$
over the entire *matrix* $\mB$ of parameters. Here $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

An entirely analogous approach to the above quickly establishes that the minimum of $\err$ is attained by taking
$$
\hat{\mB} = (\mX^T \mX)^{-1} \mX^T \mY \>.
$$
That is, in a regression setting where the response is a *vector* with covariance $\Sigma$ and the observations are independent, then the OLS estimate is attained by doing $p$ separate linear regressions on the components of the response.

Comment: Fortunately the forum rules allow adding +1 to every answer. Thanks for the education, guys!

Comment: @DWin, did you mean to post this under the comments to the question?

Comment: I suppose I could have. I had sequentially gone through the question and then all the answers (after the processing of the MathML stopped jerking around) and found each of the answers informative. I just dropped my comment on yours because it was where I stopped reading.

Comment: @DWin, yes, the rendering is a bit funky. I thought you might have intended the comment for another post since this one has no votes (up or down) and so the comment seemed to be out of place. Cheers.

Comment: Just more interface funkiness I guess. I did click it and it did turn color but it didn't "take". Fixed (I hope).

Comment: @DWin: I see. Yes, I believe the interface may limit the number of votes you can submit within a certain time span. So, if you went through and voted on each in rapid succession, it may have simply blocked later ones. That's probably to keep people from writing programs to automate voting.

Comment: @cardinal +1, useful trick. This question turned out to be a pretty good reference.

Comment: @mpiktas, yes, I agree that this question has turned out better than I would have initially guessed.

Answer (score 9):

One way which may help you understand is to not use matrix algebra, and differentiate with each respect to each component, and then "store" the results in a column vector.  So we have:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_{k}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(Y_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}X_{ij}\beta_{j}\right)^{2}=0$$

Now you have $p$ of these equations, one for each beta.  This is a simple application of the chain rule:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}2\left(Y_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}X_{ij}\beta_{j}\right)^{1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_{k}}\left[Y_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}X_{ij}\beta_{j}\right]\right)=0$$
$$-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}\left(Y_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{p}X_{ij}\beta_{j}\right)=0$$

Now we can re-write the sum inside the bracket as $\sum_{j=1}^{p}X_{ij}\beta_{j}=\bf{x}_{i}^{T}\boldsymbol{\beta}$  So you get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}Y_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{ik}\bf{x}_{i}^{T}\boldsymbol{\beta}=0$$

Now we have $p$ of these equations, and we will "stack them" in a column vector.  Notice how $X_{ik}$ is the only term which depends on $k$, so we can stack this into the vector $\bf{x}_{i}$ and we get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bf{x}_{i}\rm{Y}_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bf{x}_{i}\bf{x}_{i}^{T}\boldsymbol{\beta}$$

Now we can take the beta outside the sum (but must stay on RHS of sum), and then take the invervse:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bf{x}_{i}\bf{x}_{i}^{T}\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bf{x}_{i}\rm{Y}_{i}=\boldsymbol{\beta}$$